# Specific website won't load

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I have an 32bit Windows 7 Enterprise machine running the latest versions of Google Chrome, Firefox, IE and Java. All Windows updates has been installed as well.

When trying to open a specific website in Google Chrome, Firefox and IE, I just get a empty white screen. All other websites just work, and the problem is specific on this machine.

The website can be [found here](https://mijn.justis.nl/vog/vogorganisatie/inloggen.htm) when you click on the "Inloggen" button (which mean log in).

The browsers are all on the default settings, with JavaScript enabled.

I've tried checking the settings of the browsers and internet options, then comparing the settings where the website does work on. The settings are all the same and are both on default.

The machines are all on the same network, subnet and joined the same domain. It doesn't matter if the PC is 32bit or 64bit. I've tried both, and the site works on a 32bit and 64bit machine, except this for a few PC's.

I've also tried installing a complete new Windows image, this didn't help.

When checking the network log and opening the specific website I get only one POST result which is showed in the image below.

[image]

<sub>Click on the image for expanding it</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The "Inloggen" submit button is part of a form whose contents are submitted to

/web/wcbservlet/nl.gx.forms.wmpformengine.servlet at mijn.justis.nl

which temporarily redirects the browser, using a HTTP 302 response, to https://eh.mysmartxs.com/

Perhaps you have a firewall somewhere which blocks this?

Comment: As far as I know, I dont need to enter any required fields to "log in" to the site. Our company's firewall service is always turned to off, so it won't be able to block it right?